# How many triangles with positive area and vertices placed at the nodes of an 4 by 5 grid are there.

Tags: combinatorics

My understanding is that one has to begin by find total possible nodes which would amount to 30 possible nodes. Out of which one can find total possible triangles which would be {30 \choose 3} triangles. The problem then arises of collinear points which would cause the triangles to have a negative area and thus be deemed as invalid. My doubt is how would one determine collinear points on the diagonals and the lines of a m*n grid to these determine invalid triangles with negative areas.

Comment: The collinear triples yield zero area, not negative area.  Also, are you sure the grid has $(m+1)(n+1)$ nodes and not $mn$ nodes?

Comment: If your interpretation of $4\times 5$ is correct, you have $5$ rows of $6$ nodes. There are $\binom63$ ways to choose $3$ nodes in one row, so there are $5\binom63$ horizontal triangles of zero area. A similar calculation takes care of the vertical triangles of zero area. The slant degenerate triangles can be counted by brute force: I count $30$ of slope $1$, $4$ of slope $2$ no others of positive slope, and the same number of negative slope.

Comment: im guessing the nodes would be all possible points on a 4 by 5 grid which would includes points on the boundaries as well.

Comment: @dpvg: You’re assuming that the $4$ and $5$ refer to the lengths of the sides; in this context they often refer to the nodes themselves. You may be right, but there’s no way for us to tell without some familiarity with the source.

Comment: @Brian You missed 6 of slope 1/2. Total is 240 degenerate. Verified with code.

Comment: @DanielMathias: Yep; thanks.